# What is the appropriate way to build JSON within a Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my earlier post, [SQL Server complains about invalid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716310/sql-server-complains-about-invalid-json), I was advised to use an 'appropriate methods' for building a json string, which is to be inserted into a SQL Server table for logging purposes.  In the earlier post, I was using string concatenation to build a json string.

What is the appropriate tools/functions to build json within a Data Factory pipeline?  I've looked into the json() and string() functions, but they would still rely on concatenation.

Clarification:  I'm trying to generate a logging message that looks like this:  Right now I'm using string concatenation to generate the logging json.  Is there a better, more elegant (but lightweight) way to generate the json data?

```
{   "EventType": "DataFactoryPipelineRunActivity",    
    "DataFactoryName":"fa603ea7-f1bd-48c0-a690-73b92d12176c",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineName":"Import Blob Storage Account Key CSV file into generic SQL table using Data Flow Activity Logging to Target SQL Server",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineActivityName":"Copy Generic CSV Source to Generic SQL Sink",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineActivityOutput":"{runStatus:{computeAcquisitionDuration:316446,dsl: source() ~> ReadFromCSVInBlobStorage  ReadFromCSVInBlobStorage derive() ~> EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata  EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata sink() ~> WriteToTargetSqlTable,profile:{ReadFromCSVInBlobStorage:{computed:[],lineage:{},dropped:0,drifted:1,newer:1,total:1,updated:0},EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata:{computed:[],lineage:{},dropped:0,drifted:1,newer:6,total:7,updated:0},WriteToTargetSqlTable:{computed:[],lineage:{__DataFactoryPipelineName:{mapped:false,from:[{source:EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata,columns:[__DataFactoryPipelineName]}]},__DataFactoryPipelineRunId:{mapped:false,from:[{source:EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata,columns:[__DataFactoryPipelineRunId]}]},id:{mapped:true,from:[{source:ReadFromCSVInBlobStorage,columns:[id]}]},__InsertDateTimeUTC:{mapped:false,from:[{source:EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata,columns:[__InsertDateTimeUTC]}]},__DataFactoryName:{mapped:false,from:[{source:EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata,columns:[__DataFactoryName]}]},__FileName:{mapped:false,from:[{source:EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata,columns:[__FileName]}]},__StorageAccountName:{mapped:false,from:[{source:EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata,columns:[__StorageAccountName]}]}},dropped:0,drifted:1,newer:0,total:7,updated:7}},metrics:{WriteToTargetSqlTable:{rowsWritten:4,sinkProcessingTime:1436,sources:{ReadFromCSVInBlobStorage:{rowsRead:4}},stages:[{stage:3,partitionTimes:[621],bytesWritten:0,bytesRead:24,streams:{WriteToTargetSqlTable:{type:sink,count:4,partitionCounts:[4],cached:false},EnrichWithDataFactoryMetadata:{type:derive,count:4,partitionCounts:[4],cached:false},ReadFromCSVInBlobStorage:{type:source,count:4,partitionCounts:[4],cached:false}},target:WriteToTargetSqlTable,time:811}]}}},effectiveIntegrationRuntime:DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US)}",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineRunID":"63759585-4acb-48af-8536-ae953efdbbb0",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineTriggerName":"Manual",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineTriggerType":"Manual",   
    "DataFactoryPipelineTriggerTime":"2019-11-05T15:27:44.1568581Z",   
    "Parameters":{    
        "StorageAccountName":"fa603ea7",     
        "FileName":"0030_SourceData1.csv",    
        "TargetSQLServerName":"5a128a64-659d-4481-9440-4f377e30358c.database.windows.net",     
        "TargetSQLDatabaseName":"TargetDatabase",     
        "TargetSQLUsername":"demoadmin"   
    },    
    "InterimValues":{    
        "SchemaName":"utils",     
        "TableName":"vw_0030_SourceData1.csv-2019-11-05T15:27:57.643"   
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using Data Flow, it help you build the JSON string within pipeline in Data Factory.

Here's the Data Flow tutorial: [Mapping data flow JSON handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-json).

It can help you:

1. [Creating JSON structures in Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-json#creating-json-structures-in-derived-column)
   [image]
2. [Source format options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-json#source-format-options)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MarcJellinek You're welcome, you can try this. If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept(mark) it as answer?. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: In order to get this to work for the purpose of generating json for logging purposes, I would have to have a dataset with a single row, then use the method above to generate a logging message encoded as json, then read json elements as logging parameter values.  I'm going to give this a try but it seems like a lot of heavy lifting.  Remember, I'm just trying to generate a logging message that looks like this (see original post edit)